# repeating if in one select statement

Tags: mysql

Here is my select statement

```
SELECT A.id, A.id_item, A.id_header, 

IF (B.harga > 0, B.harga,'') AS kadar, 
IF (B.harga > 0, A.kuantiti,'') AS kuantiti, 
IF (B.harga > 0, B.harga * A.kuantiti,'') AS harga 

FROM undi_bq A, jkh_item B WHERE A.id_item = B.id AND A.id_header = '0'
```

What i'm trying to do here is i want to format results from my select statement so that

if ('B.harga > 0')

```
i will show value for columns 'kadar','kuantiti' and 'harga'
```

else

```
all these three column will be empty
```

the select statement is working fine, but i just wonder if there a way to simplify the IF statement so that i don't have to repeat it for each column.

*** by the way : Kadar = Rates, Kuantiti = Quantity, Harga = Price

Comment: Since the PHP is not relevant here, can you please edit your post down to _only_ the bare SQL? You'll get the benefit of SQL syntax highlighting and we wont have to parse PHP in our heads.

Comment: sorry sir, i'm confuse here, what do you mean with PHP, i thought i already mark my question as mysql... may be i do wrong.. help me here.

Comment: I am referring to the extraneous `$ssql .= ...` in the code.  That is PHP code, which is not relevant to the question (the question only pertains to the SQL contained within the PHP strings) so the PHP is mainly just noise for us which interferes with our visual understanding of the SQL.

Comment: ooh.. ok sorry for that mistake .. i'll try to remember that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're often better off from a performance point of view to do something like this as *two* queries, unioned together. So, instead of:

```
select xyzzy                             as xyzzy,
    if (harga > 0, harga, '')            as kadar,
    if (harga > 0, kuantiti,'')          as kuantiti,
    if (harga > 0, harga * kuantiti, '') as harga
```

you can instead do:

```
select xyzzy         as xyzzy,
    harga            as kadar,
    kuantiti         as kuantiti,
    harga * kuantiti as harga
    where harga > 0
union all
select xyzzy         as xyzzy,
    ''               as kadar,
    ''               as kuantiti,
    ''               as harga
    where harga <= 0
```

This may give a big performance increase as you're not doing per-row functions, something that rarely scales well. In most systems, the latter will greatly outperform the former (assuming you have an index on `harga` so it can locate the records faster).

Although, you should actually test the performance of both against real data. My favorite optimisation mantra is *Measure, don't guess.*

Also keep in mind that more traditional DBMS' require the types in a `union` (or `if`) to be identical. MySQL may let you choose between a character and numeric value with impunity, but that won't be portable.

Comment: Hi @paxdiablo, is there a way i can union only for kadar,kuantiti and harga not the entire select statement else it going to be quit lengthy.. may be make it as sub query of the main query ... i tried but still can't get the right syntax

Comment: @m.zam, no, unfortunately. The union should basically be two copies of the current query with the only difference being the selection of rows in each (an added `where` clause choosing `>/<= 0`, and the selection of a real column/calculation vs `''`. DBAs generally don't really worry about the size of the SQL statement itself since it's only written _once,_ whereas it's _run_ a great many times.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to shorten this to a single `IF (B.harga > 0, ...)`, as this part is evaluated per row, not for the complete query.

What is important though, is that any non-ancient version of MySQL will evaluate the condition **only once** per row, so you are not burning CPU cycles on every row.